# Error. Cannot read property ‘age’ of undefined

Tags: api, asynchronous, ionic3

Ionic 3.
I try to use auth-servise in file home.ts:

```
import { Component } from ‘@angular/core’;
import { NavController } from ‘ionic-angular’;
import { AuthServiceProvider } from ‘…/…/providers/auth-service/auth-
service’;
import { WelcomePage } from ‘…/…/pages/welcome/welcome’;

@Component({
  selector: ‘page-home’,
  templateUrl: ‘home.html’
})

export class HomePage {

    public userDetails : any;
    public responseData: any;
    public dataSet: any;

    userPostData = {“user_id”:"",“token”:""};

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public authService: 
    AuthServiceProvider) {

       const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData'));
       this.userDetails = data.userData;
       console.log(this.userDetails);

       this.userPostData.user_id = this.userDetails.user_id;
       this.userPostData.token = this.userDetails.token;

       this.getData(); 

   }

   getData(){       

      this.authService.postData(this.userPostData,'bodygraph')
        .then((result)  => {
           this.responseData = result;

           if(this.responseData.bodygraphData){ 
              this.dataSet = this.responseData.bodygraphData;
              console.log(this.dataSet);                     
           }
           else{
             console.log("No access");
           } 
     }, (err) => {
       // Error log
     });

  }
}
```

I created PHP API.
And I got data.
But I have error in file home.html:

```
 {{userDetails.name}} {{dataSet.age}} -ERROR HERE!!!!
```

Error:

```
 Runtime Error
 Cannot read property ‘age’ of undefined
```

I think that the file home.html opens earlier than I get the data.

[image: Console.log screen short]

Help me, please.

Answer (score 0):

> I think that the file home.html opens earlier than I get the data.

You are right. You just need to use **Safe Navigation Operator** in your view(html).

Do:

```
{{userDetails?.name}} {{dataSet?.age}}
```

Comment: Thank you. I also found this solution. But maybe it is possible to stop somehow loading html file, until function getData is finish?

Comment: no.. the page loading follows its own lifecycle.. based on NavController.. You will have to tell the view to display when the data is received

Comment: if you want to do something like that you will have to get the data before the page is pushed

Comment: @AlexanderDesyatnik: Suraj is right. You can also use *ngIf="yourVarible" to skip binding if it is undefinded